# table header is not relative or sticky

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap , html and css. When I scroll table header is not moving along with the data. I tried sticky-top and position-relative.  No Luck.

```
 <div class="tab-div"><table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}">
    <thead class="table-head sticky-top">

        <tr class="tr-tab">
          <td class="text-align-center text-header" >Employee Number</td>
          <td class="text-align-center text-header">Employee Name</td>
          <td class="text-align-center text-header">Designation</td>
          <td class="text-align-center text-header">Deapartment</td>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>

 <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test"/></td>
              <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test"/></td>
          </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Gone through some of the tutorials and couldn't find a solution for my problem. May be this is a problem with my understanding.  Can any one suggest a fix for this? , I have duplicated few rows to test.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I scroll the table  header content  should be visible along with the body data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a sticky table head:

HINT: add "sticky-top" to the TDs, not the thead itself!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tab-div">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="table-head">
      <tr class="tr-tab">
        <td class="text-align-center text-header bg-white sticky-top">Employee Number</td>
        <td class="text-align-center text-header bg-white sticky-top">Employee Name</td>
        <td class="text-align-center text-header bg-white sticky-top">Designation</td>
        <td class="text-align-center text-header bg-white sticky-top">Deapartment</td>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value=" test " /></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empName " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDesig " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDept " value="test "/></td>
          </tr>

 <tr>
              <td><input type="input " name="empNo " readonly class="form-control-plaintext col-md-1 value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value=" test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empName " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDesig " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDept " value="test "/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input " name="empNo " readonly class="form-control-plaintext col-md-1 value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value=" test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empName " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDesig " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDept " value="test "/></td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
              <td><input type="input " name="empNo " readonly class="form-control-plaintext col-md-1 value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empName" value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empDesig" value="test" /></td>
        <td><input type="input" name="empDept" value="test" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="input" name="empNo" readonly class="form-control-plaintext  col-md-1 value=" test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empName " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDesig " value="test "/></td>
              <td><input type="input " name="empDept " value="test "/></td>
          </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but not the way I want. I have given a color to thead. But when I scroll the color and the thead stuff is missing, a white background with header text is scrolling. Added same color for <tr>  no luck.

Comment: Again, try to give the color (background-color?) to the TDs, not the surrounding THEAD or TR.

Comment: Perfect. Solved my problem. Thanks very much. Accepting as the answer.